# Create view in Oracle SQL Developer from Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio

Tags: sql-server, oracle, database-connection

I have two databases; SQL Server uses SSMS to connect and Oracle DB uses Oracle SQL Developer to connect.

I want to create a view in Oracle database from SSMS.

I tried this code in SSMS:

```
CREATE VIEW LINKDB_ORACLE..user_oracle.ViewCreate_OnOracle 
AS 
    SELECT UserId, UserName
    FROM [dbo].[Users]
```

When I run this query, I get this error:

> The object name 'LINKDB_ORACLE..user_oracle.ViewCreate_OnOracle' contains more than the maximum number of prefixes. The maximum is 2.

How to I can query data from SQL Server use Oracle SQL Developer, if not use view method above.

I use SQL Server 2012 and Oracle 12c

Comment: Hi, in your code, after LINKDB_ORACLE you have two dots. Is this correct ?

Answer (score 0):

You can't use this syntax, it will be easier to create all views using Oracle Tools.
From Microsoft documentation:
A view can be created only in the current database. The CREATE VIEW must be the first statement in a query batch. 
[Create-view-transact-sql](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-view-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

If you have to use SSMS, you can try syntax:
`EXEC ('CREATE VIEV...') AT linked_server`

If you want to see SQL Server data from Oracle database, then check this post:
[Oracle equivalent for linked server](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/163075/what-is-oracle-equivalent-for-linked-server-and-can-you-join-with-sql-server)

Comment: your code: EXEC ('CREATE VIEV...') AT linked_server. You created view in Oracle database?

Comment: Yes. Remember that when you creating a view in Oracle, you need to refer to tables located in Oracle.

Comment: thanks @Piotr . I want create viewin Oracle from SSMS

Comment: Yes, you can do it using EXEC ('CREATE VIEV...') AT linked_server.